# ElasticsearchException[Failure running machine learning native code

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

One of my projects need to use elasticsearch and its ML functionality. When I run the system, my terminal shows:

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[Failure running machine learning native code. This could be due to running on an unsupported OS or distribution, missing OS libraries, or a problem with the temp directory. To bypass this problem by running Elasticsearch without machine learning functionality set [xpack.ml.enabled: false].]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failure running machine learning native code. This could be due to running on an unsupported OS or distribution, missing OS libraries, or a problem with the temp directory. To bypass this problem by running Elasticsearch without machine learning functionality set [xpack.ml.enabled: false].
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:618) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$11(Node.java:484) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:488) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 6 more
uncaught exception in thread [main]
ElasticsearchException[Failure running machine learning native code. This could be due to running on an unsupported OS or distribution, missing OS libraries, or a problem with the temp directory. To bypass this problem by running Elasticsearch without machine learning functionality set [xpack.ml.enabled: false].]
```

Here is my mac system config:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,1
  Processor Name:   6-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    6
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 12 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  System Firmware Version:  1554.120.19.0.0 (iBridge: 18.16.14663.0.0,0)
  Serial Number (system):   C02ZQ9F9MD6M
  Hardware UUID:    6439B42E-BDFE-5A81-AE7F-ABB8452BCDCF
  Provisioning UDID:    6439B42E-BDFE-5A81-AE7F-ABB8452BCDCF
  Activation Lock Status:   Enabled
```

One of the solution is to set `xpack.ml.enabled: false` in the elasticsearch.yml. Although this solution fixed the error, it completelt missed the point of my project which requires elasticsearch's ML functionality.

Hope to get some help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: The ML jobs are executed outside of JVM with C++ processes https://github.com/elastic/ml-cpp. The C++ executables should be compatible with your platform. Apparently they are not.
Could you check if you can find in the Elasticsearch Home directory a platform-specific directory ./modules/x-pack-ml/platform/. In the past there was a similar issue, but it is marked as solved https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/48490